# Set "json_serialization_enable" to true permanently on AWS redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, serialization, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

I am using the AWS RedShift serverless to query some s3 files which contain Parquet data. Before querying the data, I always need to run the following command:

```
SET json_serialization_enable TO true;
```

Is there a way to set [this flag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_json_serialization_enable.html) as true globally so that it is not tied to a session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set this using ALTER USER:

```
ALTER USER yourusername SET json_serialization_enable TO true;
```

This is similar to this answer: [How to change default value for parameter globally for redshift cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67131461/how-to-change-default-value-for-parameter-globally-for-redshift-cluster)